# My Search box is only searching only uppercase

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem in making my project. I have made a search box which is searching only uppercase, i don't want to make it case sensitive. 
Can some one help me. I will be thankful to you.

here is my code

```
function doSearch() {
    var searchText = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value; 

    var targetTable = document.getElementById('dataTable');
    var targetTableColCount;

    //Loop through table rows
    for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < targetTable.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
        var rowData = '';

        //Get column count from header row
        if (rowIndex == 0) {
           targetTableColCount = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.length;
           continue; //do not execute further code for header row.
        }

        //Process data rows. (rowIndex >= 1)
        for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < targetTableColCount; colIndex++) {
            rowData += targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(colIndex).textContent;
        }

        //If search term is not found in row data
        //then hide the row, else show
        if (rowData.indexOf(searchText) == -1)
            targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'none';
        else
            targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'table-row';
    }

}
```

Comment: Stack snippet is for **running code** only.

Answer (score 1):

Best approach would be to cast both to lowercase:

```
if( rowData.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) == -1 )
```

That's also the general practice when searching in a case-insensitive way.

Comment: But i m confused where shall i write it?

Comment: That's your if statement I have written; the one that searches your table, towards end of code snippet.

Comment: thanx a lot my friend It worked. I will alwyas be thankfull

Comment: If it helped you, pls consider accepting it as the answer.